# OpenGL texturing

Tags: c++, opengl, texturing

Sorry for the plea for help, but I am frustrated.

I don't know why, but I've never seemed to be able to get texturing to work in OpenGL. I would really appreciate a minimal example, so long as it only uses /gl.h /glu.h and standard C++ libraries. Any other insight would be appreciated.

Sorry for simply asking for you to write up a whole program for me, but I could really use it, since EVERY internet example I have seen uses glut. I can't compile it for some reason, and it is very annoying.

Thanks.

Comment: Then your problem is your inability to compile glut, not the need for someone to hand-code you an example that doesn't use it.

Comment: What OS? Creating a window is platform specific.

Comment: Windows, sorry not to clarify

Comment: I cannot use GLUT tutorials because I don't want to rely on GLUT in my programs.

Comment: Well, texturing is finally working. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You NEED some library or interface to create an OpenGL context** (and a window to display it).

GLUT is outdated, but still popular; good options nowadays are GLFW or SDL. I recommend GLFW.

(BTW, why did you even need to compile GLUT? Doesn't it have precompiled binaries for Windows?)

Or you can use system-specific functionality; in your case - WinAPI. However, this is a very tedious process; much unlike the portable solutions which create a window in just one or two lines of code and provide easy input handling.

Once you get your GL window up and running, **you can learn texturing** (or anything else) **from any tutorial**. The OpenGL calls will be the same, it doesn't matter how the window was created.

Comment: Again, tried that. It just won't work. I'll just need to keep trying.

Comment: Hm. Try to get [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org) and run any empty GLFW program - the [user's guide](http://www.glfw.org/GLFWUsersGuide27.pdf) has a simple Hello World code. If that works, you can proceed to learning texturing etc; if it doesn't, please describe a specific problem and we'll see what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good tutorial:

http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=06

This code does not use glut.

Comment: No, but it uses the GLaux library :/

Comment: thats true, I really cannot use that. Its far too old. (Glaux, not the tutorial)

Comment: @Alexander If you've managed to create a OpenGL render context, this tutorial should be trivial to port.

Comment: I've tried and failed, many times. I can never seem to get it right. Hopefully I will figure it all out.

Answer (score 1):

You need a window manager to create a window, for which you are going to create a context, where you can render your image. You can not do that using standard c++.

It is not clear for which OS you are targeting, but there are cross-platform frameworks, like GLUT, SDL, etc. You can also do it using xlib, if you are on linux.